# Feed published on OOTB blog template to use in Feedburner

Tags: 2010

My company write a blog which has subscribers through feedburner. We were using 2007 with the CKS:Enhanced Blog Edition which worked great as the RSS.xml file to provide feedburner was easy to locate, provide to feedburner then subscribers would receive the email for new blog posts. We upgraded to 2010 and using the OOTB blog template. What is the link to the feed for the OOTB blog template in SharePoint 2010?

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the link that comes with the "RSS Feed" located in the blog template and that seems to do the trick for anyone else who may come across this.